# Meaning of '^[0-9]+$'?

Tags: bash

What does this expression pattern `'^[0-9]+$'` check for?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ $VAR =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]]; then
    execute code
fi
```

Comment: Don't put any quotes on ^[0-9]+$, single quotes make it a literal string. =~ treats the string to the right of the =~ argument as an extended regular expression, so you don't want it to be a literal string. Use [[ "$VAR" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];

Comment: I was setting `VAR` to a non-empty contiguous string of digits and the code wasn't executing. That makes sense now as to why it wasn't executing.

Answer (score 6):

The regular expression `^[0-9]+$` will match a non-empty contiguous string of digits, i.e. a non-empty line that is composed of nothing but digits. If you want to use that regular expression in `[[ ... =~ there ]]` in `bash` 3.2 or above, then you should also leave it unquoted, i.e. `^[0-9]+$` instead of `'^[0-9]+$'`. Your code snippet should probably look like this instead:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "${VAR}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    #execute code
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

The regular expression will match the contents of VAR when VAR from start (^) to end ($) matches one or more (+) digits [0-9]. The line must contain only digits in order to match ^ and $ on either end of the [0-9]+.

Program to test the if regex comparison against a range of inputs

```
$ cat flub
#!/usr/bin/bash


for VAR in 3a3 '^[0-9]+$' 2 1919181818 flub 282_2828 '38938 2828' '3939.' '.3939'
do
    echo -n "Testing $VAR : "
    if [[ "$VAR" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "$VAR" matches
    else
        echo
    fi
done
```

Output

```
$ ./flub
Testing 3a3 : 
Testing ^[0-9]+$ : 
Testing 2 : 2 matches
Testing 1919181818 : 1919181818 matches
Testing flub : 
Testing 282_2828 : 
Testing 38938 2828 : 
Testing 3939. : 
Testing .3939 :
```

Whereas with the extended regex part quoted with single quotes only matches the literal string:

```
$ cat flub
#!/usr/bin/bash


for VAR in 3a3 '^[0-9]+$' 2 1919181818 flub 282_2828 '38938 2828' '3939.' '.3939'
do
    echo -n "Testing $VAR : "
    if [[ "$VAR" =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]]; then
    echo "$VAR" matches
    else
        echo
    fi
done



$ ./flub
Testing 3a3 : 
Testing ^[0-9]+$ : ^[0-9]+$ matches
Testing 2 : 
Testing 1919181818 : 
Testing flub : 
Testing 282_2828 : 
Testing 38938 2828 : 
Testing 3939. : 
Testing .3939 :
```

Comment: I think that your description is incorrect. The regular expression `^[0-9]+$` will only match a line that is *entirely* composed of digits. It will not match lines that merely begin and end with digits, e.g. it will not match the string `1bc`. The regular expression that *"starts with (^) and ends with ($) one or more (+) digits [0-9]"* would be `^[0-9]+.*[0-9]+$`.

Comment: Thanks, your right I misworded it, as is evident in the examples

Answer (score 1):

The test is testing whether `$VAR` contains the string `^[0-9]+$`. To test `$VAR` against the regular expression `^[0-9]+$`, remove the quotes.

The test will be true if the regular expression matches.  It matches if the string in `$VAR` contains only digits (and at least *one* digit).

Another way to do the same test is with `case` (which would make it portable to other shell besides `bash`):

```
case "$VAR" in
    *[!0-9]*)
        # string has non-digits
        ;;
    *[0-9]*)
        # string has at least one digit
        # (and no non-digits because that has already been tested)
        ;;
    *)
        # string must be empty due to the previous two tests failing
esac
```

Comment: Note however that `bash`'s (and ksh93's) `[0-9]`, in wildcards (not in REs for bash) can match a lot more than 0123456789 depending on the locale (`0123456789²³¹¼½¾٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸०१२३४५६७८০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౸౹౺౻౼౽౾೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩༪༫༬༭༮༯༰༱༲⁰⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⅛⅜⅝⅞` in a en_GB.UTF-8 locale here, note some missing digits 0 and 9 in some scripts).

Answer (score 1):

If you're unsure about the meaning of a regular expression, then use one of the many online tools. They tell you exactly which part of the expressions does what and even show matches in samples.

Here is an example from https://regex101.com/ (there are other great sites, too):
[image: Regex]

Comment: Note that that site does not give the user the ability to test standard basic regular expressions or standard extended regular expressions _specifically_, meaning that if you construct a regular expression that seems to work, there is no way to test whether it's a type of regular expression supported by `bash`'s `=~` operator or other common UNIX utilities.

Comment: True. 
Here is a site which lets you test if the regex works in bash: [http://regexraptor.net/](http://regexraptor.net/) Unfortunately it does not explain what the regex does, only if it works. Since the OP asked for the meaning of the rexexp I chose regex101